# P5.js sketch has terrible framerate on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I developed several games using P5.js and I managed to make them work around 60fps. Sadly, I discovered that they're working around 10fps on a lot of browsers including recent versions of chrome and safari. It seems that the problem come from P5.js.

Here is a very short sketch that display framerate. Works well on snippet but as soon as I make it full page it became 10 fps on many browsers.

http://pleaseletme.help/framerate/

Any idea of how to solve this issue ? I'm a bit lost.

here is the P5.js sketch

I also posted this question [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/p5-js-sketches-with-terrible-framerate-on-chrome/499)

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(frameRate(), width / 2, height / 2);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting 60fps on all my browsers (Firefox / Chrome / Opera / IE11 / Edge) - Win10 64bits

Comment: im getting 60 on FF and Chorme and 30 in safari

Comment: in Mac OS Seira for context

Comment: I'm also getting 60 FPS on Chrome.

Comment: Please link between crossposts. This has also been posted [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/p5-js-sketches-with-terrible-framerate-on-chrome/499).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how large the canvas is.  If you have a computer with a very large screen size, P5.js will have to run and render a lot more.  If you operate on a smaller canvas (say 800x600), it will run at a much higher framerate than one that is 3000x1500.